# Automatically detect URL links in a text

Tags: php, regex, url

I am creating a job announcement website.

Currently, I am stuck in dealing with **URLs** included in the **content of a job announcement**.

I can perfectly display the said content from my database to my website but **URLs** are **not detected**.

In Facebook, when you post something like that, the site automatically detect these links. **I want also to achieve this in my own website**.

[image: job announcement content picture]

Comment: This can be a complicated problem because, on the one hand, you can skip escaping and allow the browser to render markup. But there are security issues with that. More commonly, applications allow users to use _markdown_ to display rich text but you have to implement a markdown editor.

Comment: As it stands, your question is very vague. What does "How to automatically detect url links" actually mean? Do you want them to render as hyperlinks in the browser?

Comment: for example, I have this content:

Comment: Apply here! https://ph.joblum.com/job/licensing-officer-iv/1519111...
₱69,970–₱97,950 a monthFull-time
Deadline for accepting applications: March 04, 2022

Comment: I want url links to be recognized in my content, just like in facebook

Comment: here in stackoverflow, the url links were also easily detected when I commented

Comment: @waterloomatt I covered XSS in my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [A Liberal, Accurate Regex Pattern for Matching URLs](https://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls) I found the following **Regex**

> \b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:([\w\d]+)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))

## Solution

```php
/**
 * @param string $str the string to encode and parse for URLs
 */
function preventXssAndParseAnchors(string $str): string
{
    $url_regex = "/\b((https?:\/\/?|www\.)[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|\/)))/";

    // Encoding HTML special characters To prevent XSS
    // Before parsing the URLs to Anchors
    $str = htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

    preg_match_all($url_regex, $str, $urls);

    foreach ($urls[0] as $url) {
        $str = str_replace($url, "<a href='$url'>$url</a>", $str);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

## Example

```php
<?php
$str = "
apply here https://ph.dbsd.com/job/dfvdfg/5444

<script> console.log('this is a hacking attempt hacking'); </script>

and www.google.com

also http://somesite.net
";

echo preventXssAndParseAnchors($str);
```

### The output

```html
apply here <a href='https://ph.dbsd.com/job/dfvdfg/5444'>https://ph.dbsd.com/job/dfvdfg/5444</a>

&lt;script&gt; console.log(&#039;this is a hacking attempt hacking&#039;); &lt;/script&gt;

and <a href='www.google.com'>www.google.com</a>

also <a href='http://somesite.net'>http://somesite.net</a>
```

Test https://3v4l.org/85lsl

Comment: `[\w\d]+` doesn't make sense, `\d` is included in `\w`